# What Twitter access token should I use to automate tweets?

Tags: twitter, meteor, twitter-oauth

I would like to know what access token I require to achieve the following.

My Meteor app crawls various RSS feeds and makes a daily digest. I would like to automatically tweet about the daily digest when it is created, using the app's Twitter account.

As I see, in the [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview), it seems that I need to use [application owner access token](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/application-owner-access-tokens) and create my app using the app's Twitter account. Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. It's quite simple too.

1. Go to [Twitter Apps](https://apps.twitter.com/) and login with your regular twitter account
   assuming you have one, if not you need to create one.
2. Once signed in click on Create New App button.
3. Fill out the application (Name, description, and whatever else it requires).
4. Create your key and access tokens. Share those with users that you trust as they'll be used to access the twitter API to read/write information.
5. Give the application you created a "Read and Write" permission based on what you asked in the question.

Then depending on the software/language you use there's a plenty of existing packages that can help you access and obtain the information from the API.

Comment: My app's twitter account does not have mobile and cannot create a new app. My mobile is already registered with my personal account. Is there a workaround?

Comment: That's currently a bug with twitter for some reason. If it's listed in the link properly and verified then you'll need to create a ticket. https://mobile.twitter.com/settings Many users are experiencing this issue as of recently, it's not related to you specifically.

Comment: It is not a bug. My issue is different. I only have one mobile phone, and that is already registered to my personal account. Twitter requires a mobile phone to create app. My app's Twitter account cannot have a mobile phone because my phone is already registered. Any workaround?

I will accept the answer as it answers my original question.

Comment: I too have one mobile phone and use for both regular twitter and the API. Where does it say they have to be different?

Comment: Twitter does not allow duplicate mobile number. It warns me that it is already registered.